# JQGrid chamar uma função com click em uma célula passando o id da linha

Tags: jquery, javascript-eventos, jqgrid

Bom dia, preciso de 2 ajudas de vocês. Primeira vez com JQGrid.

1- Preciso acrescentar mais uma coluna na grid com uma imagem que vai chamar um modal passando o valor do ID da linha.

2- Preciso também, colocar um função que irá abrir a tela de edição com duplo click na. Ja consigo fazer com um click na linha, mais isso não me serve, precisa ser com o duplo click.

```
$(function () {
    var grid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        //url: '@Url.Action("Lista","Perfil", new { Area = "Gerenciamento" })',
        url:'/Gerenciamento/Perfil/ListaPeloDAO',
        mtype: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [
            { label: 'Id', name: 'id', width: 50 },
            { label: 'Descricao', name: 'descricao', width:380 }, 
        ],
        loadonce: true,
        pager: '#jqGridPager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 250
    });
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', 'jqGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false })
    jQuery("#jqGrid").click(function () {
        //Pega Id linha selecinada 
        var PegaIdDaGRid = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
        //Chama a tela do Editar passando o ID
        window.location = '/Gerenciamento/Perfil/Cadastro/' + PegaIdDaGRid;
    });
});
```

Comment: o que você já tentou?

Comment: Olá paulo. Na verdade eu ja consegui. Veja:

Comment: jQuery("#jqGrid").dblclick(function () {
        
        //Pega Id linha selecinada 
        var PegaIdDaGRid = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
        //Chama a tela do Editar passando o ID
        window.location = '/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Cadastro/' + PegaIdDaGRid;
       
    });
    
    function adicionarRecurso(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
        return "<a href='/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Perfil/" + options.rowId + "'>+ Perfil</a>";        
    }

Comment: obrigada. Fica pra proxima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conhecimento, segue como ficou o resultado, tudo funcionando perfeitamente, com duplo click e com imagem:

```
$(function () {

    var grid = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
        //url: '@Url.Action("Lista","Recurso", new { Area = "Gerenciamento" })',
        url:'/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Listar',
        mtype: 'GET',
        datatype: 'json',
        colModel: [
            { label: 'ID', name: 'id',width:50 },
            { label: 'codigo', name: 'codigoRepresentante', width:80 },
            { label: 'Nome', name: 'nome' , width:200 },           
            { label: 'Email', name: 'email', width:80  },           
            { label: 'Cpf', name: 'cpf', width:80  },           
            {
                label: 'Data_Inclusao', name: 'data_inclusao', formatter: 'date', width:100, 
                formatoptions: { srcformat: 'd/m/y', newformat: 'd/m/y H:s' }
            },

            { name: 'Perfil', index: 'recursos', width: 80, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: adicionarRecurso },  
            { name: 'Exceção', index: 'recursos', width: 80, align: "center", editable: true, formatter: adicionarExcecao },  
        ],

        loadonce: true,
        pager: '#jqGridPager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 50],
        viewrecords: true,
        height: 250

    });
    $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', 'jqGridPager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false })

    jQuery("#jqGrid").dblclick(function () {

        //Pega Id linha selecinada 
        var PegaIdDaGRid = grid.getGridParam("selrow");
        //Chama a tela do Editar passando o ID
        window.location = '/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Cadastro/' + PegaIdDaGRid;

    });

    function adicionarRecurso(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
        return "<a href='/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Perfil/" + options.rowId + "'>+ Perfil</a>";        
    }  

    function adicionarExcecao(cellValue, options, rowdata, action) {
        return "<a href='/Gerenciamento/UsuarioExterno/Excecao/" + options.rowId + "'>+ Exceção</a>";        
    }  
});
```